# Line wrapping Scala XML literal

Tags: scala

How can I line wrap a Scala XML literal? In the following example I would like the string to wrap after (say) 80 columns. Using a `\` as in a few other languages results in the `\` being literally included in the XML.

```
val xmlLiteral =
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent et velit vel dui aliquet facilisis ac vel quam. Ut fringilla nec nisi sed ultricies. Proin at enim sed erat rutrum pretium. Donec porttitor pharetra consectetur. </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala XML literals are whitespace sensitive. There is no direct way of doing a line wrap.

But you can always use `scala.xml.Utility.trim`:

```
scala> val x = <a><b>one two
     | three</b></a>
x: scala.xml.Elem =
<a><b>one two
three</b></a>

scala> scala.xml.Utility.trim(x)
res0: scala.xml.Node = <a><b>one two three</b></a>
```